# Django-slack unable to send bot messages

Tags: python, django, slack

I am trying to use django-slack api, I followed the path described here http://django-slack.readthedocs.io/
But I am not able to send sample bot message.

Here is my code snippet:

message.slack

```
{% extends django_slack %}
{% block text %}
Hello World!
{% endblock %}
```

in views.py

```
def index(request):
  slack_message('message.slack')
  return HttpResponse('Sent a message')
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: I tried an use an alternative api which is described in this link https://chatbotsmagazine.com/slack-bot-with-a-django-backend-101-tutorial-c1aa8ea3f15e#.hvatg8qfm, and its working great for now.

Comment: Set DEBUG = False

in code:
   
 DEFAULT_BACKEND = 'django_slack.backends.DisabledBackend' if settings.DEBUG else \
        'django_slack.backends.UrllibBackend'

Answer (score 5):

As vadimchin already mentionded this django-slack doesn't work when `DEBUG=True`.

Check [documentation about slack backend setting](https://django-slack.readthedocs.io/#slack-backend)

So the slack backend is disabled when `DEBUG=True`. I prefer to also test the slack messages by sending them to a test channel, so I have added the following to my global `settings.py`:

```
SLACK_BACKEND='django_slack.backends.UrllibBackend'
SLACK_CHANNEL='#test'
```

This will overwrite the default backend (and channel).

Answer (score 1):

You could try generating the API call on [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/package/Slack/functions/postMessage?utm_source=Stack%20Overflow&utm_medium=SlackFunctions_postMessage). I've linked you to Slack's postMessage endpoint on the platform. There you can generate an API call code snippet in python to put directly in your Django project.

You can also test out the API call within the dashboard :) The dashboard looks like this:

[image]

Just fill in your credentials and parameters, click code, and choose Python as your language.